# Using interplot to plot continuous*continuous interactions for multiple individuals

Tags: r, ggplot2, interaction

I want to produce a plot which demonstrates the effects of a continuous by continuous interaction, with one line for each individual in the dataset. I have managed to successfully plot the interaction at the population level using interplot:

```
m2<-lmer(RMR~No_Squares*Temperature+(Temperature|ID), data=female1)

interplot(m = m2, var1 = "No_Squares", var2 = "Temperature", ci=FALSE)
```

But I am at a loss as how to produce such a plot for each individual ID (i.e. to show the differences between individuals)

I have tried adding:

```
+ geom_smooth(aes(group = ID), method = "lm")
```

To the code, but this doesn't work.

Any ideas?